# FirebaseError: The datastore operation timed out

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have firestore collection with 50000 document when I'm trying to get all documents using below code I'm getting error

```
const { db } = require("./firebase");

getdata()
function getdata() {
    console.log("entered");
    db.collection("mycollection")
        .where("id", "!=", null)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            console.log("got res");
            for (let i in querySnapshot.docs) {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            }
        });
}
```

while executing this I'm getting this error

```
D:\project\project_duplicate>node index.js
entered
(node:17848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FirebaseError: The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.
    at new FirestoreError (D:\project\project_duplicate\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:266:28)       
    at fromRpcStatus (D:\project\project_duplicate\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:4522:12)
    at fromWatchChange (D:\project\project_duplicate\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:4767:35)
    at PersistentListenStream.onMessage (D:\project\project_duplicate\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:12995:27)
    at D:\project\project_duplicate\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:12928:30
    at D:\project\project_duplicate\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:12964:28
    at D:\project\project_duplicate\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\dist\index.node.cjs.js:14554:20
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:17848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:17848) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[2020-12-03T19:23:10.734Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (8.1.1): Connection GRPC stream error. Code: 1 Message: 1 CANCELLED: Disconnecting idle stream. Timed out waiting for new targets.
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems cause by ran out of memory:

> The datastore operation timed out, or the data was temporarily unavailable.

Similar to this [case](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/4561) because you have getting and returning a large collection. You should apply a [limit or batch or pagination query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) in order to avoid  running out of memory and excessive costs.